# How can I read from a CSV file into 2 ArrayLists depending on the data type I have got in the File?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, token

I'm a beginner in java and I have no clue how to read from a CSV file into 2 ArrayLists maybe using tokens and. Type. (list->Array)
Depending on the token we add to one list or another.

Update: The format of the file is fixed. This is the format:

Andrew,Nick,11,Pen,Apple,Backpack,5500.0,570.0,4700.0

> **Ex:**
>
> Name,Description,55.0,100.0
>
> Name into an ArrayList of String.
>
> 55.0 into an ArrayList of Double;

This is my code,im trying to figure out the basic first of all.

```
public class CSVRead {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

          BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Auto2.csv"));

          String data= CSVFile.readLine(); 

          while (data != null){
           String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
           for (String item:dataArray) { 
              System.out.print(item + "\t"); 
           }
           System.out.println(); 
           data = CSVFile.readLine(); 
          }

          CSVFile.close();


          System.out.println();

         } 
        }
```

Comment: Is the format of the file is fixed? Column 1 is always name and column 3 is some double value ?
If not can the format of the data change from row to row?

Comment: Hello,yes the format of the file is fixed. This is the format: Andrew Nick 11 Pen Apple Backpack 5500.0 570.0 4700.0

Comment: Can you post the format of the data with the comma separated actual format?

Comment: You can use Apache POI which also support CSV. Their documentation is very good and it is very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code. As an example I have taken index zero as the name field and the index six as the double value you need. According to the format you can get the actual field index and add it in to your lists.

```
public void loadData() throws IOException {
    List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> someDoubleList = new ArrayList<>();

    BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/leon/Desktop/Auto2.csv"));
    String data = CSVFile.readLine();

    while (data != null) {
        String[] dataArray = data.split(",");
        // Add the names to string list as the index of it is zero
        namesList.add(dataArray[0]);

        // Add the double value to double list as the index of it is six.
        someDoubleList.add(Double.parseDouble(dataArray[6]));
        data = CSVFile.readLine();
    }

    CSVFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So i have to to add them manually like add(dataArray[3]) which is Pen.etc. I can't use like a method .Type() and do it with a if if statement(object instanceof x)  or something?

Comment: Yes. According to the field of the data row you can get the index and add it to your lists. For example, if first field is name, get the index zero and add it to the names list. If the seventh field is some double value, then add it to the index 6.

Comment: You cannot check for the data type because everything is going to be just strings. As the format is fixed, best thing is to get it from the indexes.

Comment: Make sure you are not using any other array list. Use import java.util.ArrayList;

Comment: Thank you so much for everything Leon. One last question. for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++) {
             System.out.print(dataArray[i] + "\t"); 
             }  But every line from the file is on the same line,how can i print the next line to another line?